# String formatting type codes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading about the string formatting type codes, but I can't get if there is any difference between`%f` and `%F`.

The book says for `%f` "floating point decimal" while for `%F` says "same as f, but uses uppercase letters". But which letters? because if I try:

```
>>> a = 3e-15
>>> '%F' % a
>>> '0.000000'
```

So I don't understand which letters it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, quite literally, that it uses the capital letter `F` vs. the lowercase `f`.  The upper case `F` was introduced in C99 and [highlighted in `inttypes.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cinttypes/) and then borrowed from there in Python.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting `%F` and `%f`  are the same.